# How to get into BIOS setup screen on startup for Toshiba

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, toshiba-laptop

The instructions from Toshiba say to depress F2:

http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?soid=627009

> For Toshiba notebook PCs manufactured since the introduction of
>   Windows XP One or more of the following methods will be effective:
>
> F2 key method Turn the computer on. If you see an invitation to press
>   the F2 key to enter Setup, do so. The Setup screen will appear

However that is not working. Instead I end up (quickly) in the GRUB boot menu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what is happening: the last entry in GRUB is

```
System Setup
```

Selecting that one goes into the BIOS screen.